# Intent.putExtra works with EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS but not with EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID

Tags: android, android-intent, android-appwidget

Following is the code snippet of the relevant portions of my **AppWidgetProvider** class.

```
public class LargeWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int... appWidgetIds) {
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        Log.i("Trigger2" , "Large Widget");
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.widget_large);

            preLoadWeather(context , remoteViews);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, LargeWidgetProvider.class);
            intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
            intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                    0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_button_refresh, pendingIntent);

            Intent intentStartActivity = new Intent(context, WeatherActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intentStartActivity, 0);
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_root, pendingIntent2);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
        }
        LargeWidgetService.enqueueWork(context , new Intent(context, LargeWidgetService.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        ...
    }

    private void preLoadWeather(Context context, RemoteViews remoteViews) {
        ...
    }

    private String format(String rs) {
        ...
    }

    public void updateAppWidget(Context context , AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager , int appWidgetId , String city) {
        Log.i("Trigger2" , "Large Widget");
        AppWidgetManager widgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        ComponentName widgetComponent = new ComponentName(context, LargeWidgetProvider.class);
        int[] widgetIds = widgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(widgetComponent);
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widget_large);

        preLoadWeather(context , remoteViews);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, LargeWidgetProvider.class);
        intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, widgetIds);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_button_refresh, pendingIntent);

        Intent intentStartActivity = new Intent(context, WeatherActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intentStartActivity, 0);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_root, pendingIntent2);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
        LargeWidgetService.enqueueWork(context , new Intent(context, LargeWidgetService.class));
    }
}
```

Here is my code of **LargeWidgetService**

```
public class LargeWidgetService extends JobIntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "LargeWidgetService";

    public static void enqueueWork(Context context , Intent intent) {
        enqueueWork(context , LargeWidgetService.class, 0x01 , intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent) {
        ...

        AppWidgetManager widgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
        ComponentName widgetComponent = new ComponentName(this, LargeWidgetProvider.class);
        int[] widgetIds = widgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(widgetComponent);

        for (int appWidgetId : widgetIds) {
            try {
                WeatherInfo weatherRaw = new Request(this).getItems(new WidgetPrefs(appWidgetId , this).getCity(), units);
                lwPrefs.saveWeather(weatherRaw);
                updateWidget(weatherRaw);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }

    private void updateWidget(WeatherInfo weather) {
        AppWidgetManager widgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
        ComponentName widgetComponent = new ComponentName(this, LargeWidgetProvider.class);

        int[] widgetIds = widgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(widgetComponent);
        for (int appWidgetId : widgetIds) {
            ...
            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.widget_large);
            ...
            widgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
        }
    }
}
```

PS. `updateAppWidget()` in the `LargeWidgetProvider` is called only when I attach a configActivity to the widget's xml. That activity is as follows:

```
public class LargeWidgetConfigActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int mAppWidgetId = AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
        findViewById(android.R.id.content).setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this , R.color.primary));

        final Context context = this;

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            mAppWidgetId = extras.getInt(
                    AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                    AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        }

        // If they gave us an intent without the widget id, just bail.
        if (mAppWidgetId == AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
            finish();
        }

        new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
                .title(getString(R.string.pref_delete_cities_title))
                .content(getString(R.string.pref_delete_cities_summary))
                .positiveText(getString(android.R.string.ok))
                .negativeText(getString(android.R.string.cancel))
                .items(new DBHelper(this).getCities())
                .itemsCallbackSingleChoice(0, new MaterialDialog.ListCallbackSingleChoice() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onSelection(MaterialDialog dialog, View itemView, int which, CharSequence text) {
                        new WidgetPrefs(mAppWidgetId , context).setCity(text.toString());
                        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
                        new LargeWidgetProvider().updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, mAppWidgetId , text.toString());

                        Intent resultValue = new Intent();
                        resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);
                        setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);

                        finish();
                        return true;
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }
}
```

1. In the `onUpdate()` function inside the for loop, I have a line `intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);` . So whenever I click on `R.id.widget_button_refresh` in my widget, it updates all of my widgets (Code works) . The moment I change that line to `intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);` , the refresh button stops working. Any clue on how do I resolve this? (This has no relation to the Config Activity)
2. If I use the code inside the LargeWidgetProvider's `updateAppWidget()`, the button stops working. The moment I comment all the code inside that function, the refresh button starts working again. Any Idea on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the source code of [AppWidgetProvider](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.java), you'll notice that when the **ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE** action is processed, only **EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS** is going to be checked. EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID is used only for ACTION_APPWIDGET_DELETED and ACTION_APPWIDGET_OPTIONS_CHANGED.

If you change these two lines of your `UpdateAppWidget(...)` method from:

```
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, widgetIds);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
              0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

to:

```
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, new int[] {appWidgetId});
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
              appWidgetId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

you are going to get the desired result of updating just the respective widget instead of all of them.